# great expectation integration with slack

Tags: python-3.x, great-expectations

I am trying to integrate great expectations with slack using slack web hooks, i have followed the documentation of great expectation by adding validation_notification_slack_webhook  variable in  uncommitted/config_variables.yml and adding send_slack_notification_on_validation_result  action in my check point configuration, but still not received in my slack channel.

when i tried to troubleshoot this by running
validation_results = results["run_results"]

for validation_result_identifier, validation_result in validation_results.items():
actions_results = validation_result["actions_results"]

```
for action_name, action_result in actions_results.items():
    print(f"Action result for {action_name}: {action_result}")
```

i got this output:

Action result for store_validation_result: {'class': 'StoreValidationResultAction'}
Action result for store_evaluation_params: {'class': 'StoreEvaluationParametersAction'}
Action result for update_data_docs: {'local_site': 'file:///home/talal/great_expectations/uncommitted/data_docs/local_site/validations/don_projects/warning/none/20230710T103436.877563Z/522fd8bc575cb1f2e63ff88bcf4171f4.html', 'class': 'UpdateDataDocsAction'}

which do not include the send_slack_notification_on_validation_result action, have someone faced a similar issue ?

Comment: Not this issue specifically but to do custom alerts, I've created this library: https://github.com/SuperiorityComplex/data_checks/tree/main where you can use GE but also write checks for edge cases and add alerting

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue and I found if your checkpoint uses class_name `SimpleCheckpoint`, it will always override your action_list. Try to change to `class_name: Checkpoint`.